# Alterar Context Webservice usando Visual Studio 2013

Tags: json, web-service, visual-studio-2013

Gerei um webservice ussando visual studio 2013, mysql utilizando database first, ate entao tudo bem, porem quando coloquei pra gerar em json, a resposta fica da seguinte maneira:

> string xmlns="http://digits.com.br/">
>   {"PAR_ID_23":2,"PAR_RAZAO_SOCIAL_23":"GILVAN JOAO DA SILVA","PAR_SENHA_MOBILE_23":"12","PAR_MOBILE_23":null}

Porém quando vou eu queria que o retorno fosse:

> {"Android":[{"PAR_ID_23":2,"PAR_RAZAO_SOCIAL_23":"GILVAN JOAO DA SILVA","PAR_SENHA_MOBILE_23":"12","PAR_MOBILE_23":null}]}>

Encontrei esse exemplo:

> ```
>        [WebMethod]
>         [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
>         public void HelloWorld()
>         {
>             // return "Hello World";
>             JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
>             Context.Response.Clear();
>             Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
>             RegSuMsg data = new RegSuMsg();
>             data.Message = "Hello world !";
>             Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(data));
>         }
>     }
> ```

```
    public class RegSuMsg
    {
        public String Message;
    }
```

Que funciona porem não consigo adapta-lo a minha função porque usa classes:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string ConsultarParceirosTodos()
    {
        try
        {
            NegLogin negLogin = new NegLogin();
            List<parceiro_23> colecao = new List<parceiro_23>();
            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = string.Empty;

            colecao.AddRange(negLogin.ConsultarParceiroTodos());
            json = jsSerializer.Serialize(colecao);
            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Ja tentei adapta-la de varias formas mas o retorno e sempre imcompativel, se tiro o retorno o deixo Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(data)), tambem da erro na execução.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?